# Target Non-US Customers In Email Template (NVelocity)

Tags: e-commerce, customization, nvelocity, email-templates, ablecommerce

I am using Able Commerce and need to customize the Customer Order Notification email template. I believe Able uses NVelocity for its email templates customization.

I would like to display a message to Non-US customers only. In other words, I would like to prevent the US customer from seeing a message not specific to them.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very ablecommerce-specific question and since it's a commercial product I'd try asking them for support, you'll probably get a better response directly from them.

Comment: Mauricio, thanks. I also have a post on the ablecommerce forums, but need a answer urgently. Because they use NVelocity which is widely accepted, I was hoping I could get an answer here faster. Anyone know how?

Comment: the thing is, this is not related to NVelocity itself. I'm familiar with NVelocity but not Able Commerce, I can't possibly know what values Able passes to the NVelocity context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the solution, here is what I ended up using:

`#if($order.User.PrimaryAddress.CountryCode!="US")

text for international customers

 #end`

So, I pulled the primary address from the users order and displayed the international customer text if their country code was not US.

Thanks,
Joe